# error: expected identifier or '(' - c programming language

Tags: cs50

I've been wracking my brain trying to figure this out for hours. I'm getting the following error for the code below:

mario.c:5:1: error: expected identifier or '('

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void);

int blocks = 0;
do
{
    int blocks = get_int();
    printf("%d\n", blocks);
}
while (blocks > 23);
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: try removing semicolon(;) from the end of `int main(void);` line

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` after the `int main(void)` declaration

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is why I prefer the style of having the brace on the same line as the statement, I feel it would make this mistake harder to make/easier to notice.

Comment: @KarlReid, probably the best justification of that style I've heard. Much better than "I just like it better"!

Comment: @fiveclubs thanks for the tip.  I got rid of the ; after the int main(void) but still getting similar error:

mario.c:7:1: error: expected identifier or '('
do
^
mario.c:12:1: error: expected identifier or '('
while (blocks > 23);
^

Comment: @TonyBalbin it looks like you took out the braces instead of the semicolon. Should be int main(void) { ... all your code ... }

Comment: Thanks!  Worked.  :-)